# Django unable to handle concurrent request ? where did I do wrong

Tags: python, django, web

I'm sure it's because I did something wrong.

I built a website with Django. In the model, I have a subprocess call:

```
class MyModel:
    ...
    def foo(self):
        args = [......]
        pipe = subprocess.Popen(args, stdout=subproccess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

In my view:

```
def call_foo(request):
    my_model = MyModel()
    my_model.foo()
```

When I click my website where it sends async get request to this call_foo() function, it seems like my app is not able to handle other requests. For example, if I open the home page url, it keeps waiting and won't display until the above subprocess call in foo() has finished.

Does anyone know where I did wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What database are you using? Django creates a connection for every thread using the DB, and that can cause blocking if your DB runs on a single thread or is full up.

For debugging, I would try changing your sub-process to something simple that takes a long time (maybe sleeps and prints). See if that still blocks.

Comment: I'm using SQL Server